# Tapestry "/" in parameters bug

Tags: url, tapestry

If I add slash `/` to the parameter of a page, even in encoded form `%2F` I get an error.

Sample URL:

```
http://mywebsite.com/somepage?param=dfgdfg%2F
```

Error:

```
Input string 'dfgdfg/' is not valid; the character '/' at position 7 is not valid.
```

I am trying to pass whole URL as parameter (to later redirect user to that URL) so there are a lot of slashes in there.

Is this a bug? Is there any workaround?

I could theoretically replace all slashes with something else than `%2F` but that is something I would attempt after everything else fails...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I've learned this happens on Jetty only, which I use for development...

This custom service override solved the problem:

http://tapestry.1045711.n5.nabble.com/Customising-T5-URL-Encoding-tp2412550p2412551.html

Looks very hacky but works :).

Answer (score 0):

See the [Web Services More](http://jumpstart.doublenegative.com.au/jumpstart/examples/ws/webservicesmore) example on the [JumpStart](http://jumpstart.doublenegative.com.au/jumpstart/) page.  Works for me on Jetty.

The JumpStart page has many "how-to-do-this-in-Tapestry" examples.